# BSD printer not recognized by Firebird

Tags: linux, printing, lpr

I am using BSD lpr services (BSD printing on Linux).  I WAS using CUPS, but removed it in favour of the older printing system.  Now Firebird/Iceweasel thinks that there are NO PRINTERS.

What do I have to set or modify to get the printer recognized?

Thanks,

Dean

Answer (score 1):

Better late than never:  you can get a little closer to `lpr`-based printing by adding

```
gtk-print-backends = "file,lpr"
```

to your `~/gtkrc-2.0` file.  This will *not* get you a printer listing but should at least offer the possibility to enter the `lpr` command line used for printing.  That's the closest to `lpr` printing you can get nowadays.